# Android NDK - Native Library add to already existing Android Java Library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-library

I have gone through all the Android NDK tutorials and built a few simple examples. It seems to me that every example out there from Android Studio revolves around creating a native library attached to an Android application directly. I need to create a native library that is attached to an already existing Android Library. I don't see an example to do this. Is it even possible to hang a native C++ library off an already existing Android Java Library, so the Android Library has access to those native methods, without attaching both libraries (android and native) to a specific application?

Tried in Android Studio to attach a C++ native library to an already existing Android Library, and used CMake as compiler choice, the gradle does not seem to support. The CMakeLists.txt does not seem to be recognized, the "includes" folder is not generated to support the .cpp in the cpp folder, and the native library generates no links I can see to the Android Library methods.

Comment: Please explain. Your application will have a native library that will call directly (without going through Java) some native methods of a class that is part of Android framework?

Comment: A Native Library, with methods that are called from an already created Android Library directly. The Android Library can be a dependency of any application needed. Actually, just an hour ago it resolved. I downloaded the new version of Android Studio, 3.4. It noticed an error in my gradle file for the android library, and everything seemed to work after. The cpp folder within the android library built correctly, and now my android library and native library have a good communication link to call each others methods. Phew......

Comment: hey, sorry to necro this post - did you ever solve this?

Comment: I did. Yes. Let me know if the above posts aren't enough to help. I ended up having to create another folder called "include" in the cpp folder, not to be confused with the auto generated "includes". I put all my dependent c files in there and called it out in the cmake text file. The Java AAR now can communicate with the Native AAR, and the Java AAR library is what communicates with an application, any one that calls it. Jason